# Error: redefinition of enumerator, using two diferentes frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, enums, frameworks

I use two different obj c frameworks but when I try to run the project I get this error:

```
redefinition of enumerator 'UPDATE_FAIL'
```

[image]

I delete derived data but it didn't work